# pgfplots: gnuplot fails to plot series

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to plot a function containing a (converging) series. To plot this function I changed the series to a finite sum.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\begin{document}  

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
           domain = 0:1,
           samples = 501,
           ]
  \addplot+[mark = none] gnuplot[raw gnuplot] {%
    set samples 501;
    dist(x) =  x - floor(x) < 0.5 ? x - floor(x) : 1 - (x - floor(x));
    plot[0:1] sum [k=0:5] (2^(-k) * dist(2^(2^k) * x))
  };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If I do `k=0:4`, it works fine. But the example above I tried `k=0:5` and although a plot is created this plot has nothing do to with my function.

If this question should not be asked on this stackexchange, please tell me where to open a new question.

Comment: I guess is overflow in `gnuplot`; `2^(2^5)` is `2^32` which could easily be out of its range of floating point arithmetic

Comment: Ah, sounds plausible. Is there a way to use larger floating point numbers in gnuplot?

Comment: I checked, that floor(2 ** 32) is negative (in gnuplot!) the error may be there.

Comment: On my system, I get `line 0: undefined variable: sum`. Did I miss something? Is my gnuplot outdated? gnuplot 4.4 patchlevel 2

Comment: Possibly. In gnuplot 4.6 it works fine

Comment: That is a typical sign of overflow.  This discussion http://stackoverflow.com/q/14052115 seems relevant.  It also reminds us that we are off topic for TeX.SX